# Updating bootstrap accordion entry after ajax database update

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a bootstrap accordion list generated from database records. Each entry has a checkbox that when clicked, opens a modal window and data is entered.

When submitted, an ajax database update happens and the modal closes.

Rather than refresh the parent page, I want to return the updated values and change that particular accordion entry with the results.

I get the data returned correctly, but am having problems updating the entry using the following code;

```
success: function(data) {
                var received = data
                var resp = received.split('|');
                $.each(resp, function( index, value ) {
                    alert( index + ": " + value );
                });
                    var orderid= $('#modalinvOrder').val();
                var notes = '#notes' + orderid;
                var files = '#files' + orderid;
                var inv = '#inv' + orderid;
                alert(notes);
                $('#output').html(resp[1]);
                $(notes).html(resp[2]);
                alert($(notes).val());
                $(files).html(resp[3]);
                $(inv).attr('checked',true);
```

The each loop shows the values returned correctly.

the first alert shows the name of a span where I want to display notes returned from the update.
The second alert shown nothing.

How do I address the individual entry and it's elements.

Here's an example of the accordion entry

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#accordion836'><span class='bu'>BM</span><span id='BO6527' class='po'>BO6527</span><span class='orderdate'>17/04/2015</span><span class='total'>£4,250.00</span><span class='supplier'>Lafitte</span></a>
              <input type='checkbox' id='del836' data-order='836' class='delcheck' >
              <input type='checkbox' id='inv836' data-order='836' data-po='BO6527' data-bucode='LMDQBM-Borough Market' data-supplier='Lafitte' class='invcheck' >
        </h4>
  </div>
  <div id='accordion836' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
        <div class='panel-body'>
              <p><span class='depart'>Duck </span><span class='total'>£4,250.00</span><span class='delnotes'><strong>Delivery Notes</strong></br>
                    <span id='notes836'></br>
                    </br>
                    <strong>Invoice Notes</strong></br>
                    </br>
                    2015-04-20 - Euros </br>
                    2015-06-25 - Updated </span></p>
              <span class='depart filenames' id='files836'></span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards
Pete

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question without seeing the structure of the data returned to the page, could you edit in an example of the data?

Comment: The data is very simple, the problem is how to address the accordion elements. Heres the data; "Success|X|inv-2015-06-18-Pete234-po-BO9021;|32323232"

Comment: what's the value of `$('#modalinvOrder').val()` ?

Comment: All the elements in the accordion have id's including the order number so that they are all unique. .

Comment: I have changed the code or concatenate the orderid to the string to get the proper name. and I think it works. Need to do some more testing but will let you know.

Comment: No, still nothing updated until I refresh the page.

Comment: can you add a sample of the html and/or update your code above to show what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out more about the `orderid` you're getting. It sounds like `$('#modalinvOrder').val()` isn't returning what you think it is. `.val()` is used to [get values from form elements](http://api.jquery.com/val/); to get the text from other types of elements (`p`, `span`, etc), use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Is `#modalinvOrder` some kind of form input or not?

Comment: No, as I said it does have the orderid which is used in the Accordion. Yes, it is a hidden form input passed to the modal via the data-order attribute.